# Figure out DOM Element of right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu

I have used the following Code Snippet to build a custom context-menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x, y;

    document.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
        $("#rkm").css("left", x + "px");
        $("#rkm").css("top", y + "px");
        $("#rkm").show();
    };

    $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
        if (!(e.clientX >= x && e.clientX <= (x + $("#rkm").width()) && e.clientY >= y && e.clientY <= (y + $("#rkm").height()))) {
            $('#rkm').hide();
        }
    });
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('#rkm').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

And I have the following markup in HTML:

I have a lot of div boxes on one page, every box is "echoing" (PHP) some content, among other things a `a` tag, containing a specific link (with an ID). 
Now the question is: Can I somehow figure out, in which div the right click, to open the context menu, happened? Because I want to have a link in my context menu, containing a php-file, which has to be called by passing the mentioned ID (from the `a` tag).

I hope anybody can help me.

If there are some questions, feel free to ask.

Thats an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0em8wu2a/

**Edit:** Edited the fiddle, reachable [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0em8wu2a/1/). Added a jquery command to find the next a-tag. But on my server, it's not working at all (returning a "#") and on the fiddle, it always returns the url of the first div....

Comment: Can you provide a sample code in JSFiddle of how it is working so far?

Comment: can you add css and other details?

Comment: added a fiddle, same code as mine, except some styling of the div's and the difference, that my div's are generated with php and aren't there all the time

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Okay, so in every div-box, I have a specific link, containing a php-document, and an ID, handed over with get (so test.php?ID=...). Now I want a context menu, displaying specific links (to be exact, also excatly the link mentioned).. So every div needs a own context menu (or at least other links in the context menu)

Comment: Very minor comment (hence not an "answer"), but it would be more efficient to do this in a chain `$("#rkm").css("left", x + "px").css("top", y + "px").show();`.  Otherwise jquery has to find `rkm` each and every time, but with jquery functions the object is always returned, so it doesn't have find it 3 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.target` gives you the DOM object on which the click occurred. `e.target.tagName` can give you the tag name.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x, y;

    document.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        x = e.clientX;
        y = e.clientY;
        if($(e.target).is('div'))
            var targetDiv = $(e.target).find('a');
        else
            var targetDiv = $(e.target).closest('div').find('a');
        if( targetDiv !== undefined ){
            var linkVal = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + targetDiv.attr('href');
            var link = $('<a>')
                        .attr('href',linkVal)
                        .text(linkVal);
            console.log(link);
            $("#rkm").empty()
                .append(link)
                .css({
                    "left": x + "px",
                    "top": y + "px"
                })
                .show();
        }
    };

    $(document).mousedown(function (e) {
        if (!(e.clientX >= x && e.clientX <= (x + $("#rkm").width()) && e.clientY >= y && e.clientY <= (y + $("#rkm").height()))) {
            $('#rkm').hide();
        }
    });
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('#rkm').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
div#rkm {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color:black;
}
div#rkm a {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px;
    font-size:23px;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> <a href="test.php?id=1">div1</a>

    <p>....
        <br/>......
        <br/>
    </p>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<hr/>
<div> <a href="test.php?id=2">div2</a>

    <p>....
        <br/>......
        <br/>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="rkm"> <a href="#">Menüeintrag</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out, how to do it:

I used the following line:

`var url = $(e.target).find("a").attr("href");`

So now I'm always getting the href-attribute of the link, that belongs to the div I rightclicked in.