# Context Menu, hide in some areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu

In my last question, I figured out, how I can show my own context menu, with links in it, depending on the div you klick ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351247/figure-out-dom-element-of-right-click) for more information).

Now I have the problem, that I have no Idea, how I can prevent, that above the div's I wanted to show the context menu, the context menu isn't shown. To make my problem clear, 
[heres a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0em8wu2a/6/)

So in the top area, I don't want to let a context menu appear at all, in the div boxes (looking like that:

```
    <div class="altContext">
    <a href="test.php?id=1">div1</a>
    <p>....<br/>......<br/></p>
</div>
```

), I want to show my custom context menu.

The problem is, that if I don't click into a div, with the class "altContext" the next closest div is found. This is needed, because otherwise, some div's are not working when I right click on. I do this with that code:

```
if($(e.target).is('div'))
            var targetDiv = $(e.target).find('a');
        else
            var targetDiv = $(e.target).closest('div').find('a');
```

But that triggers the problem, that on the top area, the div among them is used for the right click.

Is there any compromise, to have both: The individual context menu for every div with the class "altContext" and the things above, showing no context menu at all..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0em8wu2a/7/)**

In your code you provided `if(targetDiv != undefined)` but `var targetDiv = $(e.target).closest('div.altContext').find('a')` was not returning `undefined`. So we need to check the length of the object. Also added `div.altContext` as element check to be more precise.

```
if($(e.target).is('div.altContext'))
    var targetDiv = $(e.target).find('a');
else
    var targetDiv = $(e.target).closest('div.altContext').find('a');
if( targetDiv.length != 0 ){
    var linkVal = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + targetDiv.attr('href');
    var link = $('<a>')
    .attr('href',linkVal)
    .text(linkVal);
    //console.log(link);
    $("#rkm").empty()
        .append(link)
        .css({
            "left": x + "px",
            "top": y + "px"
        })
        .show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, on the positive if-result, I already tried to add the class, but on the else-case, I forgot this.

Comment: @dreamweiver sorry about that, I had go out in a hurry.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan : looks better now